# API for obtaining and Releasing a PID

Tags: c, operating-system, fork

I have my first Hw assignment from the book. Can anyone help out in designing my code. I don't know where to start. i'm thinking of using an array with all zeros as the first step but i really don't know what to do. I don't understand how creating a parent and when i do that it should initialize a shared memory segment is this where my array should come in? The book is pretty good but really lacking in explaining exactly what i need to do in my program or and doesnt provide any sample output. Thanks for any help

> An operating system’s pid manager is responsible for managing process
>   identifiers. When a process is first created, it is assigned a unique
>   pid by the pid manager. The pid is returned to the pid manager when
>   the process completes execution, and the manager may later reassign
>   this pid. Process identifiers are discussed more fully in Section
>   3.3.1. What is most important here is to recognize that process identifiers must be unique; no two active processes can have the same
>   pid. Use the following constants to identify the range of possible pid
>   values:
>   **#define MIN PID 300 #define MAX PID 5000 You may use any data structure of your choice to represent the availability of process**
>   identifiers. One strategy is to adopt what Linux has done and use a
>   bitmap in which a value of 0 at position i indicates that a process id
>   of value i is available and a value of 1 indicates that the process id
>   is currently in use.

- int allocate map(void)—Create sand initializes a data structure for
  representing pids; returns—1 if unsuccessful, 1 if successful
- int allocate pid(void) — Allocates and returns a pid; returns — 1
  if    unable to allocate a pid (all pids are in use)
- void release pid(int pid)—Releases a pid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a parent which initializes a shared memory segment, and then creates a number of children. Each child scans the memory segment looking for a free slot (meaning a memory location offset from the base address), and returns the index of that slot as its simulated “pid”, replacing the 0 value with its child ID or some other indication that the slot is taken. This is a start

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is late. But I too came across the same question, worked out the following and wanted to cross-check it. I couldn't find any complete solution but anyway, here is what I did:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MIN_PID 500
#define MAX_PID 3000
#define cb CHAR_BIT

int sz = MAX_PID - MIN_PID + 1;

unsigned char *b;

int allocate_map();
int allocate_pid();
void release_pid(int pid);

int main() 
{
    int map = allocate_map();
    if (map == 1) {
        printf("\nData Structure initialized.\n");
        int id = 0, i = 0;
        while (i < 15) {
            int val = allocate_pid();
            printf("\nProcess %d: pid = %d", i+1, val);
            i++;
        }
        release_pid(503); printf("\nProcess 503 released.");
        release_pid(505); printf("\nProcess 505 released.");
        int val = allocate_pid(); printf("\nProcess %d : pid = %d\n", i+1, val);
    }
    else printf("\nFailed to initialize data structure.\n");
}

/* Creates and initializes a data structure for representing pids;
 returns —1 if unsuccessful, 1 if successful */
int allocate_map() {
    b = (unsigned char*)malloc((sz+cb-1)/cb * sizeof(char));
    if (b) return 1;
    return -1;
}

/* Allocates and returns a pid; returns -1
if unable to allocate a pid (all pids are in use) */
int allocate_pid() {
    int i = 0;
    int pid = b[i/cb] & (1 << (i & (cb-1)));
    while (pid != 0) {
        i++;
        pid = b[i/cb] & (1 << (i & (cb-1)));
        }

    if (i+MIN_PID > MAX_PID) return -1;
    b[i/cb] |= 1 << (i & (cb-1));
    return i+MIN_PID;
}

/* Releases a pid */
void release_pid(int pid) {
    if (pid < 500) {
        printf("\nInvalid PID: It should lie between 500 and 3000.");
        return;
    }
    int i = pid - MIN_PID;
    b[i/cb] &= ~(1 << (i & (cb-1)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter this question while reading the `Operating system concepts, 10th edition` book. I didn't find any reference to cross-check my solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MIN_PID 300
#define MAX_PID 5000

int get_random();
int allocate_map(void);
int allocate_pid();
void release_pid();

bool* pid_map;

int main() {
    // initiate pid map
    if(allocate_map() == -1){
        printf("unable to create the pid map\n");
    }

    // sample pid for feature release
    int pid1, pid2;

    // allocate pids
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i ++){
        int pid = allocate_pid();
        if(i == 3) pid1 = pid;
        if(i == 4) pid2 = pid;
        printf("PID: %d\n", pid);
    }

    // release pids
    release_pid(pid1);
    release_pid(1000);
    release_pid(pid2);

}

int allocate_map(void){
    srand(time(0));
    pid_map = malloc(sizeof(bool) * MAX_PID); // yah, allocated extra 300 pid
    return pid_map == NULL ? -1 : 1;
}

int allocate_pid(){
    int pid = get_random();
    while(pid_map[pid] == true){
        pid = get_random();
    }
    pid_map[pid] = true;
    return pid;
}


void release_pid(int pid){
    if(pid_map[pid] == true){
        pid_map[pid] = false;
        printf("Release pid %d\n", pid);
    } else {
        printf("PID %d is not associated with any process\n", pid);
    }
}


//to get a random number between max and min pid
int get_random(){
    return (rand() % (MAX_PID - MIN_PID + 1) + MIN_PID);
}
```